# Pandas dataframe - removing/ignoring rows based on datetime type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a dataframe of two columns:

```
Order     Value
1001969   1,61
2403215   301,36
2440229   1902-10-19 14:38:24
2450827   1851,07
...       ...
```

I want to do calculations on column 'Value', but this is recognized as object, because of the comma as decimal separator. However, using  `df['Value'] = df['Value'].astype(float)` results in the error: `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'`. This is caused by some errors in the data set where there is a date instead of number.

So I either need to drop these rows that contain datetime or ignore them. For some reason this is not working. I tried `df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce').dropna()` but this results in `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'`.

It seems both steps require the other to happen first. I guess `pd.to_numeric` needs floats instead of numbers with commas (objects), while converting to float first requires removing datetime values.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what are the outputs of `type(df)` and `df.head().to_dict()`?

Comment: ```type(df)``` results in 'Order' = float64, 'Value' = object. ```df.head().to_dict()``` results in {'Order': {57: 1001969.0, 400: 2403215.0, 689: 2440229.0, 742: 2450827.0}, {'Value':{57: 1.61, 400: 301.36, 689: datetime.datetime(1902, 10, 19, 14, 38, 24), 742: 1851.07}}

Comment: That can't be the output of `to_dict`. There are more `{` than `}`!

Comment: But once corrected: `df=pd.DataFrame({'Order': {57: 1001969.0, 400: 2403215.0, 689: 2440229.0, 742: 2450827.0}, 'Value':{57: 1.61, 400: 301.36, 689: datetime.datetime(1902, 10, 19, 14, 38, 24), 742: 1851.07}}) ; df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce').dropna()` works exactly as intended. You must have a typo somewhere.

Comment: I don't understand. Following ```df.head()to_dict()``` with ```df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce').dropna()``` results in ```AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'apply'```

Comment: Sure. `.apply` is a method of dataframe. What I did wasn't that. What I did is build a dataframe from the dictionary you provided (output to `.to_dict`). I wouldn't have done that if you had provided a minimal reproducible example. But since you haven't, and replied to mozway giving the output (with some errors) of `.to_dict`, I hijacked that `.to_dict()` output to try to build a dataframe similar as yours. And on this dataframe, your solution works perfectly. So, again, there must be a typo somewhere. For example, one of the same nature as what you did right now (replacing you df by a dict)

Comment: Okey, df to dict and then back to df worked, followed up by ```pd.to_numeric```. Follow up question: Let's say I have a third column with text values (object). These will all be replaced with NaN values, hence removed, resulting in an empty df.